# ViewPager unable to swipe after changing visibility

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have an Activity which has a ViewPager. In this ViewPager are 4 Fragments. One of these Fragments (let's call it MyListFragment) has a layout file with a ListView and a MapView (Google maps V2), in a RelativeLayout. Only one of these 2 Views is visible at a time. Initially, the ListView is visible and the MapView is gone. I have a Button, and when I click it, I switch the visibilities: ListView to gone and MapView to visible. When I click it again, MapView is set to gone and ListView to visible. You get the picture.
Now the problem is the following: after setting the MapView to gone and the ListView back to visible, the ViewPager won't swipe anymore. Instead, all touch events go to the ListView (which is a normal vertical ListView). I broke this up in a few steps, and checked when I could or could not swipe the ViewPager.

1. ListView is visible, MapView is gone: everything behaves normally.
2. Setting ListView to gone: everything behaves normally.
3. Setting ListView back to visible: everything behaves normally.
4. Setting ListView to gone, MapView to visible, MapView back to gone: everything behaves normally.
5. Setting ListView to visible: !!! the ViewPager won't swipe anymore on this Fragment !!!
6. Setting the ListView to gone: everything behaves normally.

It's weird because step 5 seems to be the same state as step 1. Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fragment_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/fragment_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_padding_bottom"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_padding"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_padding"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_padding"
    android:text="Show on map"/>
```

Here is some of the `onCreateView` code:

```
this.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
this.mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
this.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Here is what happens in the onClick for the button:

```
            if(this.listView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                this.listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                this.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.buttonSwitch.setText("Show in list");
            }
            else
            {
                this.listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                this.buttonSwitch.setText("Show on map");
            }
```

If I need to provide another piece of the code, let me know. Any help would be appreciated because I can't seem to find the cause for this bug.

Comment: Same problem here! Did you got any solution/workaround?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I found a workaround, it's not ideal though. When switching from the map to the list I disable all gestures on the map. When I switch back, I enable them again.

Comment: Thanks mate while i also managed to workaround the issue but your's seems like an easy one!

Comment: Thanks, Its worked for me also.

Answer (score 0):

just enable and disable like:-

java:-

```
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false); // true / false with Visible / Gone
```

Kotlin:-

```
 googleMap?.uiSettings?.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
```